# Como si - ¿cláusula autónoma?

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

> Me estaba mirando fijamente a los ojos. **Como si dijera "no me delates
>   por favor"**.

¿Se debe considerar la oración comparativa como una oración independiente (desde el punto de vista sintáctico)? La RAE dice (45.10l) que *como si + subjuntivo* se emplea en oraciones independientes pero allí se trata de oraciones exclamativas (*¡Como si el peligro pudiera pasar alguna vez!*). No creo que mi ejemplo sea lo mismo y estoy confundida...

Answer (score 1):

La oración está mal puntuada. Debería ser:

> Me estaba mirando fijamente a los ojos(,) como si (me) dijera/estuviera diciendo: "No me delates por favor“.

En este caso, se trata de una estructura comparativa. Se utiliza subjuntivo porque, además de exigirlo la forma "como si", la persona no lo dijo y simplemente se lo está imaginando.

La exclamativa:

> ¡Como si el peligro pudiera pasar alguna vez!

también requiere subjuntivo. La principal diferencia es que en este caso la oración es independiente, pero la fundamentación semántica es similar: el peligo no puede pasar. La exclamativa enfatiza esa imposibilidad. Veamos otro par de oraciones:

- Comparativa: *Hablaba como si fuera fácil resolver el problema.* (no lo era)
- Exclamativa: *¡Como si fuera fácil resolver el problema!* (no lo es)

Comment: ¡Gracias! Entiendo que la oración está mal puntuada pero el traductor (español!) la ha traducido de esta manera. Y ahora mi tarea es definir si esta oración es independiente o no (a pesar del hecho que va precedida de un punto)

Comment: @Aurora La comparativa sólo podría ser "independiente" como un fragmento de oración, no como una oración propiamente dicha. Por ejemplo, si decimos: *Hablaba con mucha confianza. Como si fuera fácil resolver el problema*, la segunda oración puede sonar como una exclamativa (sólo que sin signos de exclamación), como descalificando la confianza con que hablaba. Si queremos que sea realmente comparativa, debe unirse a la oración anterior: *Hablaba con mucha confianza, como si fuera fácil resolver el problema*.